# Run cargo command in subdirectories with user-specified arguments

Tags: command-line, zsh, string

I've a directory structure like:

```
rust/
├── dir1/
│   └── Cargo.toml
└── dir2/
    └── Cargo.toml
```

I want to create a zsh script that'll run from the `rust` directory, and for each subdirectory with a `Cargo.toml` file, run `cargo` command with user-specified arguments.

Example:

`run.sh "test -- --ignored"` should run `cargo -v test -- --ignored --manifest-path ./dir1/Cargo.toml` and `cargo -v test -- --ignored --manifest-path ./dir2/Cargo.toml`.

The double quotes are necessary to prevent the shell from messing with the `--`. User may pass other arguments without `--`.

I've tried `find . -name 'Cargo.toml' -type f -print -exec cargo -v "$@" --manifest-path {} \;`, but got the error "error: no such subcommand: test -- --ignored". Clearly, the whole thing is passed as a string, not as individual strings.

How to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shell doesn't *mess up with `--`*.

Just do:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
for toml (**/Cargo.toml(N.)) cargo -v "$@" --manifest-path $toml
```

And call it as:

```
that-script test -- --ignored
```

Using zsh globbing has several advantages over `find`:

- hidden files and directories are ignored (add the `D` qualifier if you do not want it)
- the list is sorted
- it's possible to have arguments containing `{}` be passed to `cargo`.

---

If you wanted to pass one argument to the script and the shell to split it on space characters and the resulting words to be passed as separate arguments to `cargo`, you'd do:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
for toml (**/Cargo.toml(N.)) cargo -v ${(s[ ])1} --manifest-path $toml
```

Or for `$1` to be split on characters of `$IFS` (space, tab newline and nul by default) instead: `$=1`

Then, you'd call:

```
that-script 'test -- --ignored'
```

But that would mean the user can't  pass an argument containing spaces (resp. IFS characters) to `cargo`.

Alternatively, you could tell the shell to do shell tokenisation and quote removal on that one argument using the `z` or `Z[options]` and `Q` parameter expansion flags using `"${(Q@)${(Z[n])1}}"` (`Z[n]` for `n`ewline to also be accepted as delimiter, see also `z[Cn]` to also recognise and strip `C`omments, `@` within double quotes to preserve empty elements), maybe doing that tokenisation only once to avoid having to do it every time in the loop, and even store them in `$argv` (aka `$@`) so we're back to square one:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
argv=( "${(Q@)${(Z[n])1}}" )
for toml (**/Cargo.toml(N.)) cargo -v "$@" --manifest-path $toml
```

And then be able to do:

```
that-script "test -- --opt1='foo bar' --opt2=$'blah\nblah' --opt3 ''"
```

For instance, and `test`, `--`, `--opt1=foo bar`, `--opt2=blah<newline>blah`, `--opt3` and the empty string to be passed as separate arguments to `cargo`.

But again, that's way overkill when you can get the user to pass all arguments separately to your script (in the syntax of *their* shell / language, while the `Z`/`Q` flags above expects `zsh` quoting syntax) and the  script to pass them along to `cargo` with the standard `"$@"` as in the first example above.

---

Now, as it turned out, your problem was that the `--manifest-path path/to/Cargo.toml` was to be before the `--` option delimiter of the `test` subcommand. You could always insert those arguments in the list of arguments passed by the user with something like:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
for toml (**/Cargo.toml(N.)) (
  argv[2,0]=(--manifest-path $toml)
  cargo -v "$@"
)
```

That way, when the user invokes `that-script test -- --ignored`, the script ends up calling `cargo -v test --manifest-path path/to/Cargo.toml -- --ignored`.

Comment: Nope, as I said, `run.sh test -- --ignored                       
error: could not find Cargo.toml in /path/to/rust or any parent directory`, just tried with your code. Running with the second option, the error changes to `error: the manifest-path must be a path to a Cargo.toml file`

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar, you said the command had to be `--manifest-path ./dir2`, not `--manifest-path ./dir2.toml`

Comment: I see, that was my bad, I'll update my question. The manifest path is indeed the path to the `Cargo.toml` file.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar, also that *error: could not find Cargo.toml in /path/to/rust* error suggests `cargo` needs to be run within the directory than contains `Cargo.toml`. Maybe `(cd $toml:h && cargo...)`

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar I wonder if the `--manifest-path ./dir2` should come before `--`. It should be an option to `cargo test`, not to the test run by `cargo test`

Comment: `for dir (**/Cargo.toml(N:h)) (cd $dir && cargo -v test -- --ignored)` is the only thing that works. I think I'm going to leave it here, and accept your answer.

Comment: So, turns out for `--manifest-path $toml` needs to go after the sub command, not at the end, like so `cargo test --manifest-path $toml -- --ignored`. Thus, there's no way to accept arbitrary commands from users.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar, you could always insert those two args after the first argument provided by the user: `cargo -v "$1" --manifest-path $tom1 "${@[2,-1]}"`. Or `argv[2,0]=(--maniphest-path $tom1)` and keep using `"$@"`